# Minimizing a convex piece-wise linear function of short $(\max, +)$ circuit length

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, convex-optimization

If $a_{ij}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix of real numbers, and $b_j$ are $n$ more real numbers, then 
$$\max_i  \sum_j (a_{ij} x_j + b_j)  \qquad (\ast)$$
is a convex piecewise linear function of $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We can minimize it efficiently using linear programming.

I want to minimize an expression of the form
$$\sum_h \max_i  \sum_j (a_{hij} x_j + b_{hj}) \qquad (\dagger)$$
where $a_{hij}$ is an $\ell \times m \times n$ array of integers of bounded size and $b_{hj}$ is an an $\ell \times n$ array of integers of bounded size.

> Is there a method to do this, polynomially in $(\ell, m, n)$?

Note that $(\dagger)$ is equivalent to an expression of the form $(\ast)$, so it is convex and piecewise linear, but writing it that way involves the $\max$ of $m^{\ell}$ terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Introduce variables $y_{hi}$ together with constraints 
  $y_{hi}=\sum_j (a_{hij} x_j + b_{hj})$ for all $h$ and $i$.
- Introduce variables $z_h$ together with constraints 
  $z_h\ge y_{hi}$ for all $h$ and $i$.
- Then minimize $\sum_h z_h$.

The resulting linear program can be solved in time polynomially bounded in $\ell, m, n$ and the logarithm of the largest cost coefficient.

(I am not sure whether you are asking for a strongly polynomial solution. 
This seems to be out of reach.)

Comment: Thanks! (If I am allowed to say that on this site.)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer are there sites where you're not? Sounds sad to me that a site would enforce a certain level of incivility.

Comment: When I click on the add comment box, it says "avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks"." I know that MO and math.SE don't take that seriously, but I think some cites do. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged